# How Can I See the XML Schema Associated with an XML Namespace?

Tags: xml, xsd

I have created a ovf file using vmware ovftool:

```
<Envelope vmw:buildId="build-931074" 
          xmlns="http://schemas.dmtf.org/ovf/envelope/1"  
          xmlns:cim="http://schemas.dmtf.org/wbem/wscim/1/common"  
          xmlns:ovf="http://schemas.dmtf.org/ovf/envelope/1"  
          xmlns:rasd="http://schemas.dmtf.org/wbem/wscim/1/cim-schem/2/CIM_ResourceAllocationSettingData"  
          xmlns:vmw="http://www.vmware.com/schema/ovf"  
          xmlns:vssd="http://schemas.dmtf.org/wbem/wscim/1/cim-schema/2/CIM_VirtualSystemSettingData"  
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
....//deleting some contents
<OperatingSystemSection ovf:id="74"  
                        vmw:osType="windows7_64Guest">
```

How to understand the following line:

```
xmlns:vmw="http://www.vmware.com/schema/ovf"
```

All I can get from it is that this declares the namespace prefix `vmw`.  However, how can I see the schema file for this namespace? I mean without the schema file, we cannot get the vocabularies derived from that namespace. The "vmw:osType" is a vocabulary from the namespace. Thanks in advance for your helpful insights.

Comment: In general, you can't see the schema unless they give it to you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to ask the `XSD` creator for that schema. However, the main `XSD` file will usually have a `schemaLocation` pointing to the schema's physical location.

Also, the XSDs are located [here](http://schemas.dmtf.org/ovf/envelope/1/dsp8023_1.1.0.xsd). And they have a nice documentation [here](http://pubs.vmware.com/vcd-51/index.jsp?topic=/com.vmware.vcloud.api.reference.doc_51/doc/operations/GET-OperatingSystemSection.html).

Comment: I don't know about "usually". "Sometimes" would be more accurate.

Comment: If the xml do not provide the location of XSDs that provide the vocabularies, how can it actually be interpreted?    For example, how can the user know the info of vmw:osType?

Comment: @galuano1, The XSD you specified is not the vmw XSD file, it's the standard ovf 1.0 XSD file. That is not what I am asking for.

Answer (score 0):

If all you can get from the namespace declaration `xmlns:vmw="http://www.vmware.com/schema/ovf"` is that it declares the namespace prefix `vmw`, one reason is that that is in fact all it reliably does. Namespace names can be used for a wide variety of purposes, but the only thing guaranteed by the design of namespaces in XML is that they provide unique strings so that different people can use the same local names in XML documents without name conflicts.

One reason for using URIs as namespace names is that URIs can be dereferenced by human beings seeking further information, as you are.  In this case, the URI owner appears not to have provided any human-readable information at the namespace URI, so you're on your own.

If you can validate the document you show, then your XSD validator is finding a schema document for that namespace somewhere; it's likely (though not absolutely guaranteed) that that schema document is pointed to either from the XML instance document, in an `xsi:schemaLocation` attribute, or from an `xs:import` element in one of the schema documents the validator is consulting.

And of course you can always try asking the namespace owner, or using search engines, to help find schema documents for the namespace.  Any schema documents you do find may, of course, be authoritative or non-authoritative definitions of the namespace.

Good luck.